# Parsing a string containing a date in a specific format into a Date object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, string

I'm learning Javascript as a new language, and I figured a good way to get used to how JS handles reg exp and string manipulation is to parse a string containing a date into a Date object.

I have a string in the form `"2005-05-28"`.  What is the best Javascript-y way to parse that into a Date object?

Comment: @all: **No**, that string can't be used reliably with `new Date` or `Date.parse`. Not yet. (There was an early, now-deleted answer saying you could, and now a second one.) That will fail on all currently-released versions of IE, for instance: http://jsbin.com/otite5 That ISO 8601 subset stuff was only standardized as of the 5th ed. spec (~a year ago). Previously, there was *no* standard string-to-Date conversion in the spec (just the statement that it "should" handle whatever Date-to-string output). The new stuff is a very welcome addition, but it'll take time for implementations to catch up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Non-RegExp

I don't know about "best", but you don't need a regex:

```
var str = "2005-05-28";
var parts = str.split("-");
var dt = new Date(parseInt(parts[0], 10),
                  parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1,
                  parseInt(parts[2], 10));
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/iveyi5)

That uses `String#split` to break the string on the `-` characters, then the `Date` constructor that accepts year, month (starting with 0), and day (starting with 1).

#### RegExp

Mind you, if you really *want* to use a regexp, you can:

```
var str = "2005-05-28";
var parts = str.match(/^(\d{1,4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})$/);
if (parts) {
    var dt = new Date(parseInt(parts[1], 10),
                      parseInt(parts[2], 10) - 1,
                      parseInt(parts[3], 10));
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/iveyi5/4)

That uses a regex with capture groups, doing the match via `String#match`, which returns an array with the full match at index `0` followed by the capture groups. But for my money, the regex isn't really buying you anything.

#### Beyond

If your date strings get more complicated or may vary, I'd look at farming the problem out to a library like [DateJS](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/). But if your format is that regular, you're golden.

Answer (score -1):

That format is acceptable for a standard JS date. So you only have to do:

```
var dateObject = new Date("2005-05-28");
```

EDIT: The above is wrong and TJ is right; I've been busted with a lazy answer. And it even parses incorrectly in Firefox, subtracting one from the date.

Seeing that this question was trickier than I thought, I ran some tests carefully. IE (and others) will accept a slash instead of a dash (implementation trumps specification). So, the above will work with a simple replace():

```
var dateObject = new Date(("2005-05-28").replace("-", "/"));
```

Note that I also tested this successfully with MM/DD/YYYY:

```
var dateObject = new Date("05/28/2005");
```

So the slashes will parse in all major browsers (including IE6).

Comment: This ISO date format is only officially supported by versions of JavaScript which implement ECMA-262 5th Edition, so this will not work in most MSIE web browsers, for example.

Comment: *"That format is acceptable for a standard JS date"* No, it isn't (yet) -- see the note I put on the question (that note wasn't there when you answered, don't worry). I put the note there because yours was the second answer saying this, the first having been deleted when it was pointed out that it was wrong.